# Get the real filename of file entity

Tags: files, 9

I'd like to get the real filename of a file entity.

My code is like this

```
    $filenames = [];
    foreach ($entity->$field->referencedEntities() as $image) {
      // Filename.
      $media = Media::load($image->id());
      $fid = $media->field_media_image->target_id;
      $file = File::load($fid);
      $filenames[] = $file->getFilename();
    };

    return $filenames;
  }
```

But filename returns the label of the file entity like so. `my-image.jpg` and using `getFileUri()` returns `public://images/my-image_0.jpg` I think because the image has been replaced at some point.

What I would like is just `my-image_0.jpg` but I can't seem to find a function to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The File class itself, in [`File::preCreate()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21src%21Entity%21File.php/function/File%3A%3ApreCreate/9.4.x) uses the following code.

```php
  // Automatically detect filename if not set.
  if (!isset($values['filename']) && isset($values['uri'])) {
    $values['filename'] = \Drupal::service('file_system')
      ->basename($values['uri']);
  }
```

In you case, the following code should be used.

```php
$filenames[] = \Drupal::service('file_system')->basename($file->getFileUri());
```

In a context where dependency injection is available, the [*file_system*](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.services.yml/service/file_system/9.4.x) service should be injected.